# How to create IN,OUT for %type in postgres,i Tried this

Tags: java, postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetProduct(_product_id  NUMERIC,
                                     _product_name OUT products.product_name%TYPE,
                                     _category OUT products.category%TYPE,
                                     _quantity OUT products.quantity%TYPE,
                                     _price OUT products.price%TYPE)
RETURNS VARCHAR
Language 'plpgsql'
AS
$$

DECLARE flag BOOLEAN;
BEGIN

SELECT product_id,product_name,category,quantity,price 
INTO _product_id,_product_name,category,quantity,price FROM products 
WHERE product_id=_product_id;
flag=true;
RETURN flag;
END;
$$
```

I tried it this way, but it is showing some error like

```
NOTICE:  type reference products.price%TYPE converted to numeric

ERROR:  function result type must be record because of OUT parameters
SQL state: 42P13
```

Answer (score 0):

The notice is probably because you are using domains, and that is reduced to the base type.

The error indicates that the `OUT` parameters and the declared function return type contradict each other: the function does not return a single `varchar`, but a composite value consisting of several elements.

So follow the error message and declare the function as `RETURNS record`.